# Build a multinomial logit model for a sample from a multinomial distribution

Tags: r, statistics, multinomial

I have data from several subjects on what proportion of their time they spent in each quarter of a square-shaped room. Here is a sample data:

```
a <- rmultinom(12, 100, c(0.1, 0.4, 0.3, 0.2))
a / apply(a,2,sum)

### not running, but I would like to have something like this
# glm(a ~ 1, family=multinomial("logit")
```

I would be interested in the intercept, as my expectation is that they will spend most of their time in e.g. quarter 2.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the documentation for the stats package, there is no glm family = multinomial. glm does not fit this type of model. Perhaps the glmnet or nnet packages will suit your needs.

There are several resources on this topic. For example, the following [tutorial](https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/r/dae/multinomial-logistic-regression/) is the first result from a google search using the criteria: r multinomial regression.